# WWW returns "Null" (I think I cant connect to php file) - C# Unity

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

So I have a script in unity that connects to a MySQL database through a PHP script. The PHP script is working fine, but I can't connect to the PHP file from Unity (C# script). The URL for the WWW is localhost and that is for XAMPP (don't know if that is the problem)

Here is my code:

```
private string CreateAccountUrl = "http://localhost/CreateAccountScript.php";
IEnumerator CreateAccount()
{
    WWWForm Form = new WWWForm();

    Form.AddField("Email", CEmail);
    Form.AddField("Password", CPassword);
    Form.AddField("Username", CUsername);

    WWW CreateAccountWWW = new WWW(CreateAccountUrl, Form);

    yield return CreateAccountWWW;
    if (CreateAccountWWW.error != "Null")
    {
        Debug.LogError("Cannot Connect to Account Creation!");
    }else
    {
        string CreateAccountReturn = CreateAccountWWW.text;
        if (CreateAccountReturn == "Success")
        {
            Debug.Log(CreateAccountReturn);
            CreateAccountMenuHolder.SetActive(false);
            ConfirmEmailMenuHolder.SetActive(true);
        }else if (CreateAccountReturn == "DB Error")
        {
            Debug.LogError("DB ERROR!");
        }else if (CreateAccountReturn == "Can't connect to DB (connect)")
        {
            Debug.LogError("Can't connect to DB (connect)");
        }else if (CreateAccountReturn == "Can't connect to DB (select)")
        {
            Debug.LogError("Can't connect to DB (select)");
        }
    }
}
```

Please ignore the error debugs, they were only for testing...

---

If you need my PHP code please say it, because I really need the help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to do in the line `if (CreateAccountWWW.error != "Null")`? Comparing the error using a "Null" string doesn't seem to be what you want to do? With your inequality, that will always succeed and hence give you a logged error. Don't you simply mean `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CreateAccountWWW.error))`

Comment: @Bart You need to put this as the answer. Or `if (CreateAccountWWW.error != null)`.

Comment: Yes, it was a very stupid problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: When I press the button that starts the IENumerator it gives an error: `ArgumentException: The thing you want to instantiate is null. Unity Engine.Object.CheckNullArgument (System.Object arg, System.String message) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEngineObject.cs:102)` Do you know a solution for this?

Comment: Not without knowing what line in your code causes this. And that's probably best asked in another question if you can't resolve it yourself. But make sure you collect all relevant information first.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There probably is no error, but with your current code you'll always think there is one. You have the following error comparison:

```
if (CreateAccountWWW.error != "Null")
{
    Debug.LogError("Cannot Connect to Account Creation!");
}
```

That is, you're comparing the possible error message against the string `"Null"`. That is not what you want to do. You want to check if your `error` member is actually null. That is

```
if (CreateAccountWWW.error != null)
```

Or, alternatively

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CreateAccountWWW.error))
```

That should do the trick.